# Como dibujar un rectángulo inclinado en Python

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

No se me viene ninguna idea de como poder hacer que un rectángulo este inclinado a 45 grados en python.

Comment: Tienes que tener un array con las coordenadas de los cuatro vértices (una vez rotados) y usarla para hacer un `polygon()`. En cuanto a cómo obtener esas coordenadas, puedes partir de las del rectángulo sin rotar y aplicar senos y cosenos, o bien trabajar con número complejos en los que la rotación se hace multiplicando por otro complejo de módulo 1 y fase igual al ángulo que quieras rotar.

Comment: Si al obtener el cuadrado en 0 grados, como podria aplicar senos y cosenos a ese objeto ejemplo: canvas.create_rectangle(width/4-5,height/32,width/4 - 12.5+10,height/32 + height/16,fill="Black") es el código que uso para crear un rectángulo como multiplicaría esa fila de código por un coseno o un seno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya te lo respondieron en un comentario, pero aquí te agrego algunos segmentos de código que espero te sean útiles.

Para hacer transformaciones espaciales en un objeto cualquiera, necesitas determinar dos puntos importantes:

- El tipo de transformación
- Puntos que conforman al objeto

### Rotación

Para el caso de la [rotación](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Movimiento_de_rotaci%C3%B3n), la transformación es equiparable a dos traslaciones, el componente en *x* y el componente en *y* al que apuntan.

Dado el punto **P(x, y)** el valor de **P'(x, y)** estará dado por las siguientes fórmulas.

- *x' = x * cos(angulo) - y * sin(angulo)*
- *y' = x * sin(angulo) + y * cos(angulo)*

Siendo *x'* e *y'* las coordenadas del punto **P(x, y)** rotado.

### Puntos del Polígono

Debido a que tenemos una figura elegida, en este caso, el rectángulo, determinamos entonces que este posee cuatro puntos fijos que deben tener consistencia entre sí, los llamaremos:

- BottomLeft
- BottomRight
- TopRight
- TopLeft

Para mantener consistencia entre los resultados, puedes en vez de registrar la posición individual, almacenar una relación entre ellos, es decir, las coordenadas del punto origen, la anchura y la altura del rectángulo, de este modo, sin importar el ángulo de rotación puedes calcular los demás puntos con un método de traslación agregando también la rotación correspondiente.

Siendo entonces la posición de *BottomRight* por ejemplo respecto a *BottomLeft* (Punto Origen)

- **P(x, y)**: *BottomLeft*
- **Q(x, y)**: *BottomRight*
- **R(x, y)**: *TopRight*
- **S(x, y)**: *TopLeft*

*Qx = Px + anchura*

*Qy = Py*

*Rx = Px + anchura*

*Ry = Py + altura*

*Sx = Px*

*Sy = Py + altura*

### Ejemplo

El resto, corresponde al sistema que uses para realizar gráficos, no conozco muy bien Tkinter, pero dado que lo mencionaste en las etiquetas me tomé la libertad de escribir un breve código de ejemplo que espero sirva a tus objetivos, al menos como una base.
Toma la consideración de que, hice por default que el punto InferiorIzquierdo sea el eje de rotación.

```py
import math
import tkinter

class Rectangle(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h, a):
        self.__x = x
        self.__y = y
        self.__w = w
        self.__h = h
        self.__angle = a

    @property
    def angle(self) -> float:
        return self.__angle

    @angle.setter
    def angle(self, value: float):
        if value > 360 or value < 0:
            self.__angle = value % 360
        else:
            self.__angle = value

    @property
    def botleft(self) -> tuple:
        return self.__x, self.__y

    @property
    def botright(self) -> tuple:
        return Rectangle.rotate(
            self.__x,
            self.__y,
            self.__w + self.__x,
            self.__y,
            self.__angle
        )

    @property
    def topleft(self) -> tuple:
        return Rectangle.rotate(
            self.__x,
            self.__y,
            self.__x,
            self.__h + self.__y,
            self.__angle
        )

    @property
    def topright(self) -> tuple:
        return Rectangle.rotate(
            self.__x,
            self.__y,
            self.__w + self.__x,
            self.__h + self.__y,
            self.__angle
        )

    @staticmethod
    def rotate(bx, by, x, y, a) -> tuple:
        nx = x - bx
        ny = y - by
        s = math.sin(math.radians(a))
        c = math.cos(math.radians(a))
        return (
            (nx * c - ny * s) + bx,
            (nx * s + ny * c) + by
        )





def main():
    master = tkinter.Tk("Prueba")
    canvas_width = 640
    canvas_height = 480
    w = tkinter.Canvas(master, width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height)
    w.pack()
    r = Rectangle(200, 200, 100, 50, 0)
    w.create_polygon([*r.botleft, *r.botright, *r.topright, *r.topleft], outline="#C3C3C3", fill="yellow", width=3)
    r.angle = 45
    w.create_polygon([*r.botleft, *r.botright, *r.topright, *r.topleft], outline="#C3C3C3", fill="#A2A2A2", width=3)
    r.angle = -75
    w.create_polygon([*r.botleft, *r.botright, *r.topright, *r.topleft], outline="#C3C3C3", fill="#C212B2", width=3)
    tkinter.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Dicho código simplemente dibuja 3 rectángulos (El ángulo se mide para este caso desde el eje de las abscisas en sentido de las manecillas del reloj) los colores los elegí meramente al escribir sin conocer el resultado.